# Realm Query Notification not firing using Kotlin

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm not able to get Realm Query Notifications to fire in Android using Kotlin. I've tried the full (1) and lambda (2) syntax for this separately:

```
object DataService {

    val realm: Realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

    var allDogs: RealmResults<Dog> = realm.where(Dog::class.java).findAll()

    fun start() {

        // (1)
        allDogs.addChangeListener(object: RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>> {
            override fun onChange(element: RealmResults<Dog>?) {
                print("Ping?")
            }
        })

        // (2)
        allDogs.addChangeListener {
            // This listener doesn't fire when I create managed the Dog object below
            print("Ping?")
        }

        realm.executeTransaction {
            realm.createObject(Dog::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with this line from the documentation:

> Change listeners only work on Looper threads. For non-looper threads,
>   you manually have to use Realm.waitForChange() instead.

Comment: You will get an exception if trying to register a listener on a thread that doesn't support it. So something else must be at play here. Do you perhaps close the Realm before the callback happens?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior That's good to know. No, I'm not closing the Realm.

Comment: Listeners will also not be called if the RealmResults is GC'ed. However it looks like you are creating a singleton object which shouldn't be GC'ed?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior correct.

Comment: @BryanBryce Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This happens not because you're using kotlin, it does because you're not keeping any reference to the RealmResult objects, if you are creating listeners for them, save the results first as properties or class members and then add the listeners.